# My texts are not showing up delivered. Does this mean I could have been blocked?

Tags: iphone

My texts are not showing up delivered.  Does this mean I could have been blocked?  Or did they put it on Do Not Disturb?  Messages were delivered yesterday morning, but everything after that is not showing delivered.

Answer (score 1):

No,

When a a user blocks a number on an iPhone and someone else with an iPhone sends a message, it appears delivered.  There is no way for someone to know they were indeed blocked.

Maybe the phone is off.

http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/mobile-phone/have-i-been-blocked-in-ios-7-who-blocked-me-ios-8-iphone-ios-9-3476005/

Answer (score 0):

There are various reasons why your message hasn't been delivered. It could mean that they haven't received your message because they do not have Internet access, their device must be turned off or they might have blocked you.